# How to fix 'No secure protocols supported'?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ubuntu-18.04, certbot

I have a personal website which I'm trying to set up to use HTTPS.

I'm using an Amazon Lightsail instance with Ubuntu 18.04 and Apache/2.4.29 on it. Opened port 443 using both AWS dashboard and ufw. I also made sure openssl version is up-to-date. I have used certbot, installation completes fine, I restarted webserver but when I go to ssllabs.com to test, I get:

> Assessment failed: No secure protocols supported

Now, I have 3 websites served by the webserver, DocumentRoot is set to default /var/www/html and I created a conf file for each site in /etc/apache/sites-available as example.com.conf, with a VirtualHost listening to *:80 only. All sites are tested and works fine with the .conf files.

When I ran certbot, I got a file in /etc/apache/sites-available called example.com-le-ssl.conf with this in it:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

At this point, I expected it to work since the guide on https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache.html says nothing else needs to be done.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you have to enable SSL for each site using `SSLEngine on`? Otherwise you are running an HTTP host without SSL/TLS on the 443 port.

Comment: Yes. I have solved it by removing 000-default-le-ssl.conf, example.com-le-ssl.conf and changing example.conf like to include a VirtualHost for _default_:443 with SSLEngine on.